# Image resize issue using GD

Tags: php, image, resize, gd

I have successfully resized images using GD library. I resize any image to 350 x 250, the problem is tat some pictures don't look good (stretch) when they are resized as i am resizing them to a fixed size. I have a space of 350 x 250 where resize picture needs to be fit, I don't mind if the pic size is smaller than 350 x 250 as long as it does not stretch. How do i solve this problem?

```
                      $save = "$directory/" . $file_name; //This is the new file you saving
                      $file = "$directory/" . $file_name; //This is the original file

                      list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file) ; 
                      $modwidth = 350; 
                      if ($width > $height) {
                      $y = 0;
                      $x = ($width - $height) / 2;
                      $smallestSide = $height;
                    } else {
                      $x = 0;
                      $y = ($height - $width) / 2;
                      $smallestSide = $width;
                    }

                      $diff = $width / $modwidth;

                      $modheight = 250; 
                      $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight) ; 
                      $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ; 
                      imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height);
                      imagejpeg($tn, $save, 100) ;
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using your calculated vars (different, x, y). You'll want to pass imagecopy the calculated proportional size and offset based on your calculations to avoid stretching

Comment: got it... completely missed that. all make sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this function I've written some time ago:

```
    public function resize($img, $width, $height, $stretch = false)
    {
        $temp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagealphablending($temp, true);
        imagesavealpha($temp, true);

        $bg = imagecolorallocatealpha($temp, 0, 0, 0, 127); // Background color
        imagefill($temp, 0, 0, $bg);

        if ($stretch)
        {
            imagecopyresampled($temp, img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, imagesx($img), imagesy($img)); 
        }
        else
        {          
            if (imagesx($img) <= $width && imagesy($img) <= $height)
            {
                $fwidth = imagesx($img);
                $fheight = imagesy($img);
            }
            else
            {
                $wscale = $width / imagesx($img);
                $hscale = $height / imagesy($img);
                $scale = min($wscale, $hscale);
                $fwidth = $scale * imagesx($img);
                $fheight = $scale * imagesy($img);
            }
            imagecopyresampled($temp,                             
                $img,                                      
                ($width - $fwidth) / 2, ($height - $fheight) / 2,   
                0, 0,                                              
                $fwidth, $fheight,                                 
                imagesx($img), imagesy($img)               
            );
        }
        return $temp; 
    }
```

if you say not to stretch the image, it will calculate a new size making it fit your new size.

use it as:

```
...
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
$resized = resize($image, 350, 250, false); // false = don't stretch
imagejpeg($resized, $save, 100);
...
```

now store $resized on the disk using imagepng() for example.

Comment: Your math looks familiar, I think that's what I've done.  Your code references $this, but is demonstrated outside of an image context. This could confuse a reader.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't remember where I found this scale math. Probably here on stackoverflow too... and I'm sorry for the "$this" mistake... I've extracted it from my Image class... Now its fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wulf... Just one thing I wanted to ask is that if I don't stretch, the size of the pic will be always 350 x 250 or sometimes less than that depending on the original picture size?

Comment: Sometimes it will be less than that... It'll try to keep the aspect ratio to avoid distorting the whole image and turning it into a whole mess ;). For example: 700x500 image will take it down exactly into 350x250 because the ratio are equals. But if try you resize an image of 800x500 it will scale it down to 350x218 and center it. It'll try to fit the image into your bounding box.